# Removing smart quotes from css tags in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, css

I've imported a Word document into a MySQL database, [utf8_general_ci]. One column has html code:

```
<p class=“hangi”><b>Robert ALGAR</b>, b. 1435.</p>
```

These smart quotes do not work in internet browsers. The PHP code that I tried to change them to block quotes is not working, i.e. not detecting the curly quotes and changing them to block quotes:

```
    $sql =  "UPDATE  `lwadb`.`ancestorIndex` SET  `descendants`='".$this->convert_smart_quotes($desc)."' WHERE `ancestorIndex`.`surname` ='".$entry."';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result) {echo "</br>ENTRY UPDATEED";}
else{echo "Error updating record: ";  print_r($this->mysqli->error_list);}
}

function convert_smart_quotes($string) { 
    $search = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151)); 
    $replace = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-'); 
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

Comment: First I do not understand how you "imported" an MS-Word document into a database. Then, why do you get html markup from that? Next, what do you mean by "smart quotes"? That alternate quote character? Why can't you simply replace that? Last: what do you mean by "is not working"? Or are we meant to _guess_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see a problem here. Just replace those two quote characters:

```
<?php
$input = '<p class=“hangi”><b>Robert ALGAR</b>, b. 1435.</p>';
$output = str_replace(['“','”'], '"', $input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: This is an example from a document that another person gave me to put on www.averykin.com. The 300 page document was converted to a csv, so that PHP could put it in MySQL. I don't want to correct every line, as I type with one finger.

Comment: Well, obviously you can read the content of `$input` from a database. Obviously you can store the result of the replacement back into the database. I considered that as obvious, thus not worth mentioning. My code is meant to demonstrate as short and clear as possible that the core issue you posted can very easily be solved. So the issue with what you call "smart quotes" not getting interpreted as you expect by browsers. The goal of an answer here is not to give you a finished script you can copy and paste. You are still required to think yourself.

Comment: Now see, if I was blocked from this site, I'd spend two more days on Windows-1252 and Utf-8 encoding!

Comment: Indeed, the internal MS-Windows encoding is a huge annoyance. Just as many other details of those systems. I never understood why people stick with it.

Comment: Why is it that some programmers think they can raise their own self worth by belittling novice programmers?

Comment: Are there such programmers? I do not know. I just tried to understand your comments (indeed I seemingly failed). Do not be offended by me miss understanding those comments you gave. I only tried to make sense of them. I do not see where I "belittled" you. I apologize if you have that impression. That was not my intention. Have fun!